# Pushing to heroku fails due to sqlite3 on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite

I've seen multiple questions, all with the same problems as me. I tried all the solutions proposed, such as making the following my Gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end
```

Added, committed, and nothing. Still the same issue when I run `git push heroku master`:

```
em::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.   
tmp/build_d2c698fb-cf76-40cd-b046-9866c3432e8b/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
   checking for sqlite3.h... no
   sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
   'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
   and check your shared library search path (the
   location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
```

I tried installing Xcode to see if that solves it, but it didn't. Ran `brew install sqlite3` which also didn't solve it.

I also checked the dependencies of my gems in my Gemfile, with `gem dependency` and also checking the `Gemfile.lock` file, which shows no dependencies for the sqlite3 gem.

I can't find a solution to this problem from existing questions. Maybe I skimmed over something I am missing, but I can't find it.

Some extra information:

```
$ rails -v
Rails 4.1.1

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-darwin13.1.0]

$ gem -v
2.2.2

$ sqlite3 -version
3.7.13 2012-07-17
```

Comment: Is this change committed in your Git repository **before** pushing to Heroku?

Comment: Yes, running `git status` shows no staged or unstaged changes.

Comment: it would be easiest if you post a link to the github repo and people could look at the code and figure it out instead of asking you to post a bunch of stuff until we find it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is under a private company repo, so I can't really supply all the code.